# Virial ratio behaviour

Tags: astrophysics, star-systems, newtonian-gravity

I think I didn't understand something about virial theorem for an $N$-body system, for instance the behaviour of virial ratio $T/\Omega$, with $T$ kinetic energy and $\Omega$ gravitational potential energy. As far as I understood, if the system is stationary, than virial ratio is $0.5$. This means on the other hand that the system is not expanding nor collapsing. But the behaviour of virial ratio is something like the plot in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362633/). Here the system starts from $T/\Omega < 0.5$, so it starts  collapsing and than reach a maximum. I would expect this maximum to be at $T/\Omega \sim 0.5$, since once the collapse stops the system is not accelerating nor decelerating, but it's about $0.75$. If the system is stationary at $0.5$ how can that maximum (and the next minimum too) be explained? I don't understand how virial ratio has a single value since it actually oscillates until converging to a specific value.

Comment: What does $T$ and $\Omega$ mean? The question becomes clearer if that is explained.

Comment: @AndersSandberg Presumably those are the kinetic and potential energies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ratio $T/\Omega$ tells you about the *acceleration* of the system - or more specifically, the second derivative of its moment of inertia - it does not tell you about the velocity.

If the system collapses because it has $T/\Omega<0.5$, then when it reaches $T/\Omega=0.5$ it stops *accelerating*. That doesn't mean it stops collapsing. It overshoots in the same way that if you compress a spring it goes beyond the equilibrium position before bouncing back once the *deceleration* becomes large.

NB: I answered the question (of which your question is a subset) that you linked to in the same way.

Comment: Yes I understood the system can be considered as an oscillating spring, but I was confusing something about the acceleration/deceleration part, you're right. Ok, so supposing the system is collapsing, after $T/\Omega$ reaches $0.5$ from negative values, the system decelerate (so acceleration sign changes) until it stops collapsing when $T/\Omega$ reach the peak right?